# .net c# sql string to date conversion error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am having convserion error for database using SQL in visual studio.

The database I am using is a normal sql server database.
It is given to me as my assignment.

This is my query method is my webservice

```
 [WebMethod]
    public bool search(string ddate, string dairport, string aairport, string seat)
    {
        int seat2 = Convert.ToInt32(seat);
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(ddate);

        String query1 = "SELECT * FROM Flight_Schedule S WHERE S.departure_date = '24/09/2011'";

        using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, connect);
            connect.Open();
            SqlDataReader result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                if (result.Read())
                {
                    return true;
                }

            finally
            {
                result.Close();
                connect.Close();
                connect.Dispose();
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

There is no issue with normal queries like :

```
"SELECT * FROM Flight_Schedule S WHERE S.origin_airport_code = '" + dairport + "'";
```

Error :

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
   at AirportService.AirportServices.search(String ddate, String dairport, String aairport, String seat) in C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebService2\AirportService\AirportServices.asmx.cs:line 47
```

Comment: Your "normal query" (second example) is just RIPE for abuse... that is a DEADLY query. I could kill your server with that web-accessible method.

Comment: verify the format of your date

Comment: marc gravell it is a school assignment which no 1 would kill. the value '24/09/2011' is copied from the database.

Comment: @user904406 part of the problem here is that you keep thinking about dates as strings. Dates ***are not strings***. At least, unless you are doing it wrong. Also, the value `24/09/2011` is not even how most DBs would *display* it by default (dd/MM/yyyy vs MM/dd/yyyy etc). Hence why parameters avoid all this mess; it will pass the *actual* date value (a floating point number with value 40808.0 in this case)

Answer (score 7):

You should handle the date-time parsing logic (in your accepted format) inside the C#, and pass that down as a parameter, i.e.

```
String query1 = "SELECT * FROM Flight_Schedule S WHERE S.departure_date = @departureDate"
```

and add a `SqlParameter` with the `DateTime` value you want; that way... no problems. No parsing at the DB, and no injection risk. And query-plan re-use too. Wins all round.

For example:

```
DateTime when = DateTime.Parse(ddate); // better to use ParseExact and formally state the format you are using
const string query1 = "SELECT * FROM Flight_Schedule S WHERE S.departure_date = @departureDate";

using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(conn))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, connect))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("departureDate", when);
        connect.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader result = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
           ... etc
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is @DepartureDate for? how do i use it?

Comment: @user904406 that is the *parameter* that you would add; 2 secs, I'll flesh out more of the example (look for an edit)

Answer (score 1):

Marc Gravell is absolutely right. But try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM Flight_Schedule S WHERE S.origin_airport_code = '" + dairport.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "'";
```

Comment: i do not have .format function for my string. how do i use it?

Comment: sorry, it should be dairport.toString("yyyMMdd")

Answer (score 0):

Your error says **"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."**

Replace this line

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(ddate);
```

To

```
IFormatProvider theCultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", true);
DateTime theDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(ddate, "mm-dd-yyyy", theCultureInfo);
```

Try this out...

Comment: sorry i dont think it has to do with convert. i had removed it and the error came from the 1st sql query which is "SELECT * FROM Flight_Schedule S WHERE S.departure_date = '24/09/2011'". a very simple query that shouldnt give any error. the 2nd sql query is just a normal query with a string of the airport code (not date).

Answer (score -1):

As a rule of best practice using SQL date, if you have to specify date in your SQL query, always try to use ISO format (yyyy-MM-dd). In most cases it will prevent any conversion errors to appear.

In your code:

```
"SELECT * FROM Flight_Schedule S WHERE S.origin_airport_code = '" + ddate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
```

Kris